# Does C# support nested strongly typed tree structure?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I would like to know if C# has a way of defining **strongly-typed** nested jagged arrays **without** using `object[]`.

Something like:

```
var nested = new {1, 2, {3, {4, 5}, 6}, 7};
```

I would like to have a nested array of `int`.

Consider this array below:
`[[1, 2, [3]], 4, [5], [[[6]]]]`

This is how I've done it:

```
var myNestedJagged = new object[]
{
    new object[]
    {
        1, 2, new object[] {3}
    },
    4,
    new object[] {5},
    new object[] {new object[] {new object[] {6}}}
};
```

Comment: The only way I think you could start to strongly type this Jagged Array is by creating classes and using generics withinin those classes to represent your Jagged Array

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I would like to know if there's a way of doing it using something like `new int[][] { }`

Comment: This is so ridiculously easy with javascript, but C# seems to have its limitations with such dynamic array

Comment: No I do not think you could express a jagged array like that C#, pros and cons to every programming language

Comment: Hate to nitpick, but this is not a jagged array. A jagged array is an array that contains arrays of different lengths, such as `{ { 1 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4}, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } }`.

Comment: You are right @MichaelGunter. That's why I tried naming it a nested-jagged.

Comment: I think you just want a node list (tree structure). There is nothing language native that would support this though, you have to create your own type(s).

Comment: @Leandro but javascript is not strongly typed :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think to improve it something like this. This is strongly-typed, and it allows you to have separate logic depending upon type of node (by either doing explicit `is` checks to determine which type of node, or by doing some sort of OO technique where an operation is described as an abstract method in the base `Node` and implemented separately in `Tree` and `Leaf` according to how each should behave, or by implementing a [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)).

```
// all items are nodes
abstract class Node
{
}

// a tree is just a collection of nodes; it has no value
class Tree : Node
{
    public Tree(params Node[] children)
    {
        Children = children;
    }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Node> Children { get; }
}

// a leaf is just a value; it has no children
class Leaf : Node
{
    public Leaf(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public int Value { get; }
}
```

However, the construction is kinda ugly.

```
var myTree = new Tree(
    new Tree(
        new Leaf(1),
        new Leaf(2),
        new Tree(
            new Leaf(3)
        )
    ),
    new Leaf(4),
    new Tree(
        new Leaf(5)
    ),
    new Tree(
        new Tree(
            new Leaf(6)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use, you could use tuples:

```
var a = (1, 2, (3, (4, 5), 6), 7);
var b = ((1, 2, (3)), 4, (5), (((6))));
```

The limitation is that after you create them you can't (easily) resize them.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't create a 1-tuple using tuple-syntax as `(x)` already has a meaning which it had prior to the introduction of tuple syntax (it resolves to simply, `x`)